# Does a (tungsten-halogen) calibration lamp keep calibrated if unused over a period of several years?

Tags: radiometry

We have a calibration lamp at work that is NIST traceable. It's a tungsten-halogen source that's used for radiometric measurements, so we have a table of power per wavelength. These lamps typically come with 900 hour bulbs, but must be re-calibrated every 50 hours. I believe that this is due to deposition on the inside of the bulb, as the filament disintegrates over time [[1]](http://zeiss-campus.magnet.fsu.edu/articles/lightsources/tungstenhalogen.html). There are also issues with the filament diameter changing a

This lamp has barely been used, I think perhaps 10-15 minutes as a power-on check when it was first purchased. However the calibration is from 2010. For anything rigorous we'd pay to get it re-calibrated, but this takes weeks and is expensive. But, for doing some quick checks on our instrumentation (e.g. measuring the approximate QE of some sensors) it would be useful to know if it's remotely accurate or not at all. Given what little I know about the chemistry inside the bulb, most of the point of re-calibration is compensating for changes that occur when the filament gets vaporised.

Unfortunately we don't have a reference source to compare it to, otherwise it would be easy to check. One option would be to check using a power meter and some narrow band filters, but for the sake of argument assume we don't have an optics laboratory!

- How close to the known calibration is this lamp likely to be?
- If it's likely to have changed, how long can you leave a calibrated system (without power-on) before it should be re-calibrated?
- If it's changed, what effects cause this?
- Are there other effects, e.g. noble gas loss from the bulb, that are significant over a period of a decade?

Comment: This is an excellent experimental question however it's very specialist knowledge, so you may only get educated guesses here. The first thing I'd try is to look for any standard, NIST or otherwise, that defines the calibration and check whether it specifies time between calibrations, and whether that is running time or dormant time or a weighted mixture of the two, and then compare your 7 years dormancy with the standard. If the globe is helium filled, I believe helium does leak into the bulb and could become - but my only reference is laboratory "folklore" that says one should run ....

Comment: .... an unused HeNe laser from time to time for a minute or so to reverse any helium absorption into the glass and keep the instrument in working order.

Comment: The bulbs in these things are more or less 'standard' incandescent lamps from what I can gather, so a tungsten filament with an argon/krypton/nitrogen mix and a bit of hydrogen bromide.

Comment: Tungsten/halogen filaments change in surface texture with age; it may be that only when hot (when crystal growth occurs by pyrolysis) is there a significant alteration.    The envelope of these lamps is quartz, not glass, so gasses inside ought not diffuse out.